# AWS dynamoDB lon/lat query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So let's I say want to store data which consists of: {longitude, latitude, anything-else}.
Then I need to query this data like so (i'll use sql like pseudo code):
`SELECT * ... WHERE longitude BETWEEN 20 AND 30 AND latitude BETWEEN 15 AND 40`

lon/lat are naturally earth coordinates. I was thinking of spliting world-wide coords into numeric "areas". But then I would need to run multiple queries to fetch data from each area in single call so this does not seem to performant.

Is this even possible to store and query such data in dynamoDB in reliable and performant way?

Comment: Related: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/geo-library-for-amazon-dynamodb-part-1-table-structure/, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-geo, and https://read.acloud.guru/location-based-search-results-with-dynamodb-and-geohash-267727e5d54f

Comment: so exactly what I considered. Unfortunate this liblary doesn't allow to have multiple index sizes to adapt basing on zoom level